# How to execute a callback on the main thread

Tags: multithreading, qt, signals-slots

I am passing an object instance to an opaque module that executes SLOT methods on my object (callback). The calling module is on a different thread. I need to execute the methods on my main thread. I thought I could do this with signals and slots, but the signaled method is still executing on the callers thread. I don't think I should be moving my object to the callers thread with moveToThread() - isn't there a mechanism to emit a signal to my applications main thread?

```
MyClass::MyClass(...)
{
   OtherClass::getInstance()->setCallback(this);
   connect(this, SIGNAL(mySignalToMainThread()), this, SLOT(doThisOnMainThread()));
}

// Public slot, called by OtherClass on its own thread.
void MyClass::someCallback() 
{
   emit mySignalToMainThread();
}

void MyClass::doThisOnMainThread()
{
   // AHHH! I am still on callers thread.
}
```

Comment: Your example misses some important information: what thread does the instance of MyClass belong to?  There are only two possibilities with activation of slots: either the slot is activated in the thread where the receiving object belongs (the default behavior), or it is activated in the thread where the signal was emitted (Qt::Directconnection).  So this should "just work", if the instance of MyClass belongs to the main thread. If it doesn't belong to the main thread, you can move it there.

Answer (score 1):

At first I thought that the emission of your signal from a thread context besides that in which MyClass resides might be a problem. However, the [Qt thread documentation states](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html):

> ...you can safely emit signals from your QThread::run()
>   implementation, because signal emission is thread-safe.

Which pretty much quashes that idea. And, you're using a `Qt::AutoConnection`, [for which the documentation states](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum):

> If the signal is emitted from a different thread than the receiving
>   object, the signal is queued, behaving as Qt::QueuedConnection.
>   Otherwise, the slot is invoked directly, behaving as
>   Qt::DirectConnection. The type of connection is determined when the
>   signal is emitted.

That last bit of particular importance. If you were to write this code:

```
void MyClass::someCallback() 
{
   Q_ASSERT(QThread::currentThread() != this->thread());
   emit mySignalToMainThread();
}

void MyClass::doThisOnMainThread()
{
   Q_ASSERT(QThread::currentThread() == this->thread());
}
```

I would expect no assert failures, but you suggest you have one. I would have to conclude that either the Qt documentation is wrong, or there's more to this problem than you've mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me. Maybe compare your implementation with what I have below and see where it may differ. I tried to follow your conventions as closely as I could, guessing at the missing details:

**my_class.h**

```
class MyClass : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  explicit MyClass(QObject *parent = 0);

signals:
  void mySignalToMainThread();

public slots:
  void someCallback();
  void doThisOnMainThread();
};
```

**my_class.cpp**

```
MyClass::MyClass(QObject *parent) :
  QObject(parent) {
  std::cout << Q_FUNC_INFO <<  QThread::currentThreadId() << std::endl;
  OtherClass::getInstance().setCallback(this);
  connect(this, SIGNAL(mySignalToMainThread()), SLOT(doThisOnMainThread()));
}

void MyClass::someCallback() {
  std::cout << Q_FUNC_INFO <<  QThread::currentThreadId() << std::endl;
  emit mySignalToMainThread();
}

void MyClass::doThisOnMainThread() {
  std::cout << Q_FUNC_INFO <<  QThread::currentThreadId() << std::endl;
}
```

**other_class.h**

```
class OtherClass : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  static OtherClass& getInstance();
  void setCallback(MyClass *cb);

public slots:
  void doCallback();

private:
  explicit OtherClass(QObject *parent = 0);

  MyClass *cb_;
};
```

**other_class.cpp**

```
OtherClass::OtherClass(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent) {
  std::cout << Q_FUNC_INFO <<  QThread::currentThreadId() << std::endl;
}

OtherClass& OtherClass::getInstance() {
  std::cout << Q_FUNC_INFO <<  QThread::currentThreadId() << std::endl;
  static OtherClass singleton;
  return singleton;
}

void OtherClass::doCallback() {
  std::cout << Q_FUNC_INFO <<  QThread::currentThreadId() << std::endl;
  cb_->someCallback();
}

void OtherClass::setCallback(MyClass *cb) {
  std::cout << Q_FUNC_INFO <<  QThread::currentThreadId() << std::endl;
  cb_ = cb;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  MyClass c;

  QThread other;
  OtherClass::getInstance().moveToThread(&other);
  other.connect(&other, SIGNAL(started()),
                &OtherClass::getInstance(), SLOT(doCallback()));
  other.start();

  QMainWindow w;
  w.show();

  return app.exec();
}
```

**Sample output:**

```
__thiscall MyClass::MyClass(class QObject *)00001108
class OtherClass &__cdecl OtherClass::getInstance(void)00001108
__thiscall OtherClass::OtherClass(class QObject *)00001108
void __thiscall OtherClass::setCallback(class MyClass *)00001108
class OtherClass &__cdecl OtherClass::getInstance(void)00001108
class OtherClass &__cdecl OtherClass::getInstance(void)00001108
void __thiscall OtherClass::doCallback(void)000015AC
void __thiscall MyClass::someCallback(void)000015AC
void __thiscall MyClass::doThisOnMainThread(void)00001108
```